# Looking for an algorithm by possibly Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that distributes nodes on a plane, such that the edges are 
all the same size. I think it is by Dijkstra, but I cannot remember. 
Anyone heard of this algorithm?

Comment: A simple counterexample: if you have one node `a` joined to a whole lot of others `b_1`, `b_2`, ... then the algorithm must lay out all the `b_i` on a circle with centre `a`. But if you also connect each `b_i` to its neighbours then you will run out of circumference if you have too many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this will be impossible. Effectively you want something similar to the finite pictures in [tilings of the plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_by_regular_polygons).

There are some simple cases - regular polygons and a few graphs which include joined polygons, but even something as simple as the complete graph for 4 points (tetrahedron) is impossible.

If you want something that tries to balance the impossible constraints, try [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and its neato program.

Comment: Thanks. Remember also that many graphs cannot be embedded in the plane without crossing edges. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph with K5 and K3,3 as simple and well known examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to create any graph with such property, then there are number of graphs that may help you with that, for instance: a line, a ring, a tree etc .. but in here, you are the one who decide what edges to include or exclude.

If you have a certain graph, and you want to have all edges of the same size then this is impossible (because of some cases) - such as: a complete graph of more than 3 nodes, a star topology with one master and more than 5 slaves, and slaves that are directly close to each other are neighbors. [I believe the cases in the other posts tells you more]

A special case, is given a graph $G(V,E)$, draw $G$ such that the length of each edge in $e \in E$ is less than a unit. This is an NP-Hard problem. [That is, you cannot decide whether an arbitrary graph $G$ is a unit disk graph]